# Sbt fork run doesn't work

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Forking.html#Enable+forking) say that

> To enable forking run tasks only, set fork to true in the run scope.
>
> fork in run := true

But when I run my app with `sbt run`(or open sbt console and then run) I don't see another process in task manager. The same case also when I set `fork := true`...

That is not the case when I run `test` task, for example.
Shouldn't the sbt create another JVM process for my app or what? Am I missing something?